# Exporting Data to CSV Pandas - issue with Foreign Characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8

I am working with a data file of customer addresses.  The source data contains foreign characters and is UTF-8 encoded.

I import the data thus:

`columns = ['userid','email','firstname','lastname','phonenumber','fax','address','unit','city','province','postalcode','listing_geopoint','website','tier']`

`data = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',', usecols=columns, encoding='utf-8')`

...execute some manipulation (de-duping mainly)

and then export the data thus:
`clinic.to_excel('clinic-'+revision+'.xlsx',index=False)`

(and I have tried this too)

`clinic.to_csv('clinic-'+revision+'.csv',sep=seperator,index=False, encoding='utf-8')`

In both cases when I open the export file I get the raw unicode value for foreign chars and not the foreign character.

e.g.
3031 boul de la Gare Cliniques Sp\u00e9cialis\u00e9es 3eme \u00e9tage

instead of the correct output

3031 boul de la Gare Cliniques Spécialisées 3eme étage

What am I missing?

Comment: Create a [mcve] with sample input data.  What are you using to view the output?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your initial data is encoded in UTF-8?

I've encountered European characters in `latin-1` encoding before so I would try reading in and exporting the csv with `(... encoding='latin1')`